# Angular 2. Issue with *ngFor, when i use Pipe

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, angular, javascript-objects

I have a component.

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'top3',
    templateUrl: 'dev/templates/top3.html',
    pipes: [orderBy],
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ParticipantService]
})
export class AppTop3Component implements OnInit {

    constructor (private _participantService: ParticipantService) {}

    errorMessage: string;
    participants: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getParticipants();
    }

    getParticipants() {
        this._participantService.getParticipants()
            .then(
                participants => this.participants = participants,
                error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
            );
    }

}
```

This component use a service, named `_participantService`. The `_participantService` retrieves an array of objects. I output my array of objects in component`s template:

```html
<h2>Top 3</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#participant of participants | orderBy: '-score'; #i = index">
            <td>{{i+1}}</td>
            <td>{{participant.username}}</td>
            <td>{{participant.score}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I use a Pipe, named `orderBy` with `*ngFor` directive. The problem is when I don`t use a Pipe and output array in this way:

```js
<tr *ngFor="#participant of participants; #i = index">
```

everything is OK, and I've got a correct result:

[image: Correct result]

But when I want to sort my object's array and use my Pipe, I don't have any output:

[image: Incorrect result]

I`ve got an undefined object in my Pipe function^

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'orderBy',
    pure: false
})

export class orderBy implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: any[], orderFields: string[]): any {
        console.log(arr);
        orderFields.forEach(function(currentField: string) {
            var orderType = 'ASC';

            if (currentField[0] === '-') {
                currentField = currentField.substring(1);
                orderType = 'DESC';
            }

            arr.sort(function(a, b) {
                return (orderType === 'ASC') ? 
                        (a[currentField] < b[currentField]) ? -1 :
                        (a[currentField] === b[currentField]) ? 0 : 1 :                                                                                                                   
                        (a[currentField] < b[currentField]) ? 1 : 
                        (a[currentField] === b[currentField]) ? 0 : -1;
            });

        });
        return arr;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: http://cdn.meme.am/instances2/500x/4383577.jpg :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you load your data asynchronously using a promise, they are null at the beginning (before the first callback defined in the then method is called).

You need to check if the are parameter is null in your pipe. If so you shouldn't execute the "order by" processing...

When the result will be there, the pipe will be called again with the data (are won't be null). In this case, you will be able to sort data...

You could try this code:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'orderBy',
    pure: false
})

export class orderBy implements PipeTransform {
    transform(arr: any[], orderFields: string[]): any {
      if (arr==null) {
        return null;
      }
      (...)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to an example of the doc of the Pipes (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#jsonpipe), you missed parenthesis :

```
<tr *ngFor="#participant of (participants | orderBy: '-score'); #i = index">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying your pipe implementation to handle null (i.e., @Thierry's answer), you could instead simply define an empty array in your component:

```
participants = [];
```

When the data comes back from the server, either push items onto the existing array,

```
.then(participants => this.participants.push(...participants),
```

or do what you already do: assign a new array.

Note that `...` is an [ES2015 feature](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#default-rest-spread).